# Unable to upload a project using GitHub-Desktop

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I've installed [GitGub-Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) on my Windows 10 machine. I tried to upload an ASP.NET MVC Core project to GitHub. I've created a repository in GitHUb.com. But when I follow [this tutorial](https://guides.github.com/introduction/getting-your-project-on-github/) and try to commit my project (by clicking `Commit to master` button shown in image 1 below), I get the error shown in screenshot 2 below. **Question**: Can someone please let me know what I need to do to upload this project on Github using **GitHub-Desktop**? This is my first time I'm trying this.:

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**:

My ASP.NET project folder has subfolder `LINQ_OUTER_JOIN_Issue_on_ASPNET` created by `Git-Desktop` as shown below:

[image]

And subfolder `LINQ_OUTER_JOIN_Issue_on_ASPNET` has other `git` folders and files as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Does that directory have a Git repository in it? If so, either move it out of the project (if it's not needed) or add it as a submodule manually. I'd recommend moving though, Git submodules can be tricky.

Comment: @Whymarrh Thank you for trying to help. Do you mean does my project folder had Git repository in it?

Comment: The directory name in the error, LINQ_OUTER_JOIN*, does it have a Git repository in it?

Comment: @Whymarrh To answer your question, I've just added an **UPDATE** section showing the `git` folders/files added by `Git Desktop` app.

Comment: If that subfolder has nothing but random Git files in it you should be safe to delete it

Comment: @Whymarrh Your solution worked (thank you). For a benefit to other users, you may want to convert your comment into a solution with a brief explanation - and I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: Glad it worked! Feel free to write up the answer yourself if you want, detailing what you did

Comment: @Whymarrh Per your advice, I've detailed my process in the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: Credit to this solution goes to @Whymarrh who helped me through his/her comments above.

Following [this tutoria](https://guides.github.com/introduction/getting-your-project-on-github/)l I dragged my ASP.NET project folder onto the main application screen of `GitHub Desktop` app. `GitHub Desktop` prompted me to turn it into a repository. After I turned it into a repository, Git created a folder named `LINQ_OUTER_JOIN_Issue_on_ASPNET` inside my project folder along with some other `.git` files. I deleted this folder and other .git files from my ASP.NET project folder. I then was able to commit by clicking on `Commit to master` button (shown in the image of my original post).